# Composer: Problem requiring meted dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to require JMS/Serializer in a client Symfony 3.4 installation.
Even if I set `"minimum-stability":"dev"`, I can't proceed.

I issued the following command `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar -v require jms/serializer-bundle jms/metadata  jms/di-extra-bundle` hoping to install all dependencies.

But this is the result:

```
Using version ^3.5@dev for jms/serializer-bundle
Using version ^2.0@dev for jms/metadata
Using version ^1.8@dev for jms/di-extra-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Dependency resolution completed in 0.623 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for jms/metadata ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by jms/metadata[2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-beta1, 2.1.0, 2.x-dev].
    - jms/security-extra-bundle 1.6.1 requires jms/metadata ~1.0 -> satisfiable by jms/metadata[1.x-dev].
    - jms/security-extra-bundle 1.6.1 requires jms/metadata ~1.0 -> satisfiable by jms/metadata[1.x-dev].
    - jms/security-extra-bundle 1.6.1 requires jms/metadata ~1.0 -> satisfiable by jms/metadata[1.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install jms/metadata 1.x-dev
    - Installation request for jms/security-extra-bundle 1.6.1 -> satisfiable by jms/security-extra-bundle[1.6.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Already tried just issuing `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar -v require jms/serializer-bundle`. Nothing change.

**Note** I'm using `composer.phar` at the last version, running with `memory_limit=-1` cause `composer` fill all my 8G ram in seconds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JMS/Serializer jms/metadata  jms/di-extra-bundle, are included into Symfony 3.4 now.

you don't need install this package :)

Serializer for example : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Di-Extra-Bundle : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Metadata : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/metadata.html